# Postgres Windows server failover

Tags: postgresql

Нужно решение для Windows аналогично таким как Pgpool, repmgr и тд. Они все заточены под UNIX like системы. 
Репликация настроена и работает в режиме master-slave. Вопрос заключается в переводе slave->master при падении текущего мастера.

Answer (score 0):

файловер можно совершить просто создав `trigger_file`, упомянутый в `recovery.conf`или `pg_ctl promote`. вы можете написать что-то свое, что будет `telnet` или `psql` мастер и в случае отказа или слишком долгого ожидания, прождав какой-то интервал, произведёт файловер.

Несколько труднее автоматизировать перевод бывшего мастера в slave. если версия достаточно новая pg_rewind ускорит процесс, в противном случае полный rebuild (а в случае больших дб это долго). конечно же можно поиграть с чекпоинтами и попыткой запустить ex-master с `timeline=latest`, но автоматизация здесь ещё более затруднительна.